# How to pass one query respose as column of another query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have to use SubClass1 as Column name of other query 
Like :

```
select SubClass1 from abc
```

how to pass Subclass1 as string in function

this is my Response of sql query

```
select Fieldname from xyz where id='1':

FieldName
----------------
SubClass1
```

Comment: What does the second query have to do with the first? They don't appear to have anything in common. SQL isn't a programming language though, you don't "pass" datasets from one query to another. If you need to reference multiple objects in a single statement you need to use things like `JOIN`, `EXISTS`, subqueries (in the `SELECT`). There is far from enough information for us to be able to answer your question here. Perhaps you could post some sample data and expected results please?

Comment: i have names in table xyz which is colum name in table abc , if i pass only two name that respective column value would be display from abc table

Comment: That doesn't explain anything I'm afraid.

Comment: this is not possibile in pure SQL .. if you want a query with variable column name You shold take at dinamic sql (server side string of sql code  .. executed runtime)

Comment: Ahh, I see. Yes, @scaisEdge is right, dynamic SQL is the route you would need to take. Really, however, this infers a design flaw in your database; which is very difficult for us to comment further on with the limited information we have.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **sub query**, select sql command.

for example in your code:

```
SELECT SubClass1 as Column1,
       (SELECT Fieldname 
        FROM xyz 
        WHERE id='1') as Column2 
FROM abc
```

please use northwind simple database and try it... also return you respond about Nested select

Answer (score 2):

You should use dynamic sql.

First store query response into a variable.

```
DECLARE @columnname varchar(50)=''
set @columnname=(select QUOTENAME(FieldName) from xyz where id=1)
```

then use that variable into dynamic sql query.

```
exec('select '+@columnname+' from abc')
```

NOTE: here example is only for single output from first query response. if you want multiple columns then you should use `COALESCE` to combine rows into a single result.

Comment: `'['+@columnname+']'` isn't injection safe. Use `QUOTENAME`.

Comment: have to returen value so i have used function

Answer (score 1):

You can use dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @variable varchar(max);
DECLARE @query varchar(max);
--Select the value you want to set as column name
SET @variable = (SELECT top(1) column_name FROM table1);
--Use the variable in the second table as column name
SET @query = 'select '+@variable+' from table2';
EXEC(@query);
```